# How to parse in array parameter from function

Tags: php, oop, curl, php-curl

I would like to ask how we can put into an array a variable reference from the current object.

In my case i have an array used for curl post and some fields are static (grant type & scope) while others (id & secret) are dynamic.

More specifivally i want to put the id & the secret as shown below:

```
  $headers = [
    'client_id='=> $this->id,
    'client_secret='=>$this->secret,
    'grant_type='=>'client_credentials', 
    'scope='=>'public' 
];
  ....
  ....
  curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

I am getting a "PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations in ..." for the second & third row.

Comment: how are you getting the `id` and `secret` and are you sure they are set before calling the `curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`?

Comment: Give more context. Are you declaring `$headers` as an instance property?

Answer (score 1):

For headers you should use something like

```
array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')
```

not associative array. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
$headers = [
    "client_id: {$this->id}",
    "client_secret: {$this->secret}",
    "grant_type: client_credentials", 
    "scope: public" 
];
  ....
  ....
  curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```